# Are Conditional Statements Automatically Universals?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, logic, first-order-logic, predicate-logic

I am trying to negate the following statement:
"For every positive number $\epsilon$, there is a positive number $M$ for which $|f(x)-b|<\epsilon$ whenever $x>M.$"
I write this in symbols as:
$$(0) \ \forall \epsilon>0 \exists M>0 (x>M \implies |f(x)-b|<\epsilon). $$
Now it is unclear to me whether the appropriate negation of this statement is:
$$(1) \ \exists \epsilon>0 (\forall M>0 \exists x (x>M \wedge |f(x)-b|\geq \epsilon))$$
or
$$(2) \ \exists \epsilon>0 (\forall M>0 (x>M \wedge |f(x)-b| \geq \epsilon). $$
It feels natural to introduce the $\exists x$, but formally speaking, the first statement did not include a $\forall x$ quantifier, so I'm not sure whether it's justified to introduce a $\exists x$ in the negation. What is the correct negation of $(0)$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$(2)$ is the negation of $(0)$.

The negation of a formula has the same occurences of *bound* and *free* variables.

In $(0)$ and $(2)$ variable $x$ is free, but in $(1)$ it is bound.

Comment: What is the formula that the OP should use?

Comment: @manooooh I would go for: $\forall\epsilon>0\exists M>0\forall x\left[x>M\implies\left|f\left(x\right)-b\right|<\epsilon\right]$
as original. Its negation is then $\left(1\right)$. In $(0)$ a statement is given that concerns $x$.

Comment: So you would go for $\forall x$. Interesting. I thought it was a free variable. Why you write the absolute value of $f(x)-b$? The statement does not say it.

Comment: @manooooh I am not saying that $(0)$ is wrong. There $x$ is indeed a free variable, and that is allowed. Btw, looking at $(0)$ I definitely read absolute values in the statement. On that I based my answer. Not so much on the original statement. It is a question about $(0)$.

Comment: @manooooh Looking at the original statement now I admit that there $x$ is free, as you remarked.

Comment: @manooooh Last thing. The words "whenever $x>M$" could be interpreted as "for every $x>M$". If it was "if $x>M$" then I would choose for free variable. In this case I am in doubt.